# Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange dispatched

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, react-navigation-drawer

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHpsS.png)

The app crashes after trying to navigate, while using expo it doesnt crash, it only on production mode and using the apk builded through Expo

I already deleted and installed the modules, and tried downgrading and updating react-navigation

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-dialog": "^5.5.0",
"react-native-dialog-input": "^1.0.7",
"react-native-root-toast": "^3.0.2",
"react-native-snackbar": "^0.5.5",
"react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.3.0",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
```

Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange" dispatched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Delete your `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file
2. Modify `react-navigation` version to `^3.11.1` in your package.json
3. Run `npm install`
4. Run `expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-navigation`
5. Run on `expo start -c`

This should setup a compatible version of react-navigation and solve your gesture issue.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: you are most welcome, if you dont mind please mark the answer as correct so anyone else can refer to it

Comment: getting the same error but not fixed for me !!!  :(